# How can I correctly send a HashMap that contains both Doubles and Strings in its values when posting to a API in JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, resttemplate

I'm using Springs rest template to post some data in JSON to an API. Unfortunately the values of my HashMap contain both doubles and Strings.

I've attempted to use a HashMap with the following datatype: HashMap, however I've found that the resulting JSON looks something like the following instead:

```
{
  "VARIABLE_1":"0.0000",
  "VARIABLE_2":"True",
  "VARIABLE_3":"String"
 }
```

Unfortunately the API I'm posting to isn't processing these doubles correctly as they are being sent as Strings. Is there someway I can be agnostic about the datatypes still but have HttpEntity format doubles correctly.

Here is an example of the code I'm actually using:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
```

...

```
public void postMethod(HashMap<String,Object> input) {

    CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new CommonsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
    HttpEntity<HashMap<String,Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(input, headers);

    ResponseEntity<Result> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, requestEntity, Result.class);
    Result result = result.getBody();
}
```

Comment: This to me looks like a good candidate for using a POJO rather than a map.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not seeing clearly where your map enters into your example code.  Is it the `input` argument to `HttpEntity`'s constructor?

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a little.  Now, which `HttpEntity` is that?  The one in Commons HttpCore is an interface; you cannot instantiate it like that (or at all).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for commenting - If I understand you correctly: Yes. I've edited the example so it's clearer

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's a spring import

Comment: @JoeC Thanks for commenting - I've avoided using a POJO so far as the list of data I want to input will change from time to time and I'm trying to avoid writing an a POJO for each list of inputs. (If I understand your meaning correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom JSON body by directly accessing the Jackson library that Spring uses:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

...

public void postMethod(HashMap<String,Object> input) {
    ObjectNode jsonBody = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : input.entrySet())
    {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();

        if (value instanceof Double)
            jsonBody.put(key, (Double)value);
        else if (value instanceof Boolean)
            jsonBody.put(key, (Boolean)value);
        else
            jsonBody.put(key, value);
    }

    // ... make headers ...

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonBody.toString(), headers);

    // ... make the post request ...
}
```

The only dumb part is that you have to cast your `value` before you call `put()` because otherwise Java calls the `put(String, Object)` method override.